# Need help with understanding this math part from the book "An Abundance Of Katherines" by John Green

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, curves, differential, standard-deviation

I am reading the book "An Abundance Of Katherines" by John Green. There is a lot of math stuff in it which I am unable to comprehend. Somebody help me out in this regard.

Here the protagonist, Colin Singleton, is trying to plot Dumpers and Dumpees in a relationship in the form of a graph. I am not able to understand what the author is trying to say. Please tell me what is the use of a differential(How do we obtain the differential?) in this graph. And I would like to know how the graph is plotted. I am not able to comprehend how the protagonist is trying to plot himself on the graph. How is he getting -4 as the differential? Please explain to me in detail if possible.

[The part of the book that I am not able to understand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgwFJ.jpg)

Kindly help me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: "differential" is used correctly, but "difference" might have been less confusing: $0 - 4 = -4$: "me" minus "the Great One" is $-4$ means "the Great One" is (four units) more Dumper than "me" is.  This is also a measure of distance between "me" and "the Great One" : "me" is $4$ units away from "the Great One" in the negative (Dumpee) direction.

Comment: The graph is representing numbers of people versus various Dumper/Dumpee numbers -- the graph is low for extreme Dumpers ("$5$") and extreme Dumpees ("$-5$").  The score of $4$ places "me" close to the left edge, about $10\%$ of the way from the left edge to the right edge, where there some people who are Dumpers at that level, but still a few who are more extreme Dumpers.  Apparently, most people are only weakly Dumper or Dumpee (high populations graphed close to the left or right of the vertical axis) and just as few are extreme Dumpers, few are extreme Dumpees (near the right edge).

Comment: @EricTowers what does the author mean by referring to the differential? And does this mean that the mean position is "0" and to the right, it is negative numbers?

Comment: The differential between two numbers is the signed distance between them -- the difference.  As described the middle position is "$0$", positive numbers correspond to being to the left and negative numbers to the right.

Comment: So, does this mean Colin is a slight dumper and slight dumpee?

Comment: Already answered.  The $4$ score is a strong Dumper, very close to the left edge (but not quite at the edge, about 10% of the way from the left to the right edge) of the diagram.

Comment: But Colin is plotted in the middle at 0

Comment: Colin is not plotted on the diagram in your image.

Comment: But it says so in the para below the graph

Comment: No.  No one person is plotted on the graph and the text does not say that any one person is plotted on the graph.  If "me" were plotted on the graph, whatever signifier would be used to represent"me" would appear on the vertical axis separating Dumpers from Dumpees, but no such signifier appears or is described to appear.

Comment: Ok, so just a hypothesis, what if someone was placed exactly at 0, what would the person be?

Comment: Indifferently Dumper/Dumpee.  The preceding discussion is about how no one person is purely either, so on the axis has no predeliction to either characteristic.

Comment: So, in the book Colin considers himself to be the Dumpee always, so why does he place himself at 0?

Comment: I am not going to speculate on the motivations of entirely fictional entities.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for explaining so patiently.